# Reading compressed gzip file in java is slower than reading normal file?

Tags: java, io

I am trying to improve file reading in my code, so I thought first microbenchmarking it, interesting result I observed are shown below.
Let me first explain each benchmark; which reads file using code:

```
private void read(String source,Blackhole blackhole) throws  IOException {
   byte[] buffer = new byte[512];
   InputStream inputStream = new FileInputStream(source);
   int offset = 0,read = 0;
   while((read = inputStream.read(buffer,0,512))!=-1){
       blackhole.consume(buffer);
       offset+=read;
   }
   System.out.println(offset/(1024*1024) + " MB read");
}
```

only difference in each benchamark is file source which is explained below:

```
compress = gzip version of orignal file which has on disk size 181MB
normal = actual file of 2.0G
normalCompressSize = actual file truncated to size of compressed file i.e. 181MB
```

Results

```
Benchmark                      Mode  Cnt  Score   Error  Units
FileReader.compress            avgt   20  5.722 ± 0.207   s/op
FileReader.normal              avgt   20  1.728 ± 0.010   s/op
FileReader.normalCompressSize  avgt   20  0.160 ± 0.004   s/op
```

Now, I can't find reason why compressed file is read at such a slow speed. I am not even using GzipInputStream to inflate data, but still it takes so much time as compared to other, especially the trucated file of same size.
Any specific reason why it is happening?
Let me know if I missed any important detail.

Edited: Added snippet to explain benchmark:

```
public static void main(String[] args) throws IOException {
  Options opt = new OptionsBuilder()
    .include(".*" + FileReader.class.getSimpleName() + ".*")
    .jvmArgs("-server")
    .forks(1)
    .build();
  try {
    new Runner(opt).run();
  } catch (RunnerException e) {
   e.printStackTrace();
  }
}
```

Benchmarks:

```
@Benchmark
@BenchmarkMode(Mode.AverageTime)
@OutputTimeUnit(TimeUnit.SECONDS)
public void compress(Blackhole blackhole) throws IOException {
  read("~/Documents/data.csv.gz",blackhole);
}
@Benchmark
@BenchmarkMode(Mode.AverageTime)
@OutputTimeUnit(TimeUnit.SECONDS)
public void normalCompressSize(Blackhole blackhole) throws IOException   {
  read("~/Documents/data181MB.csv",blackhole);
}
@Benchmark
@BenchmarkMode(Mode.AverageTime)
@OutputTimeUnit(TimeUnit.SECONDS)
public void normal(Blackhole blackhole) throws IOException {
  read("~/Documents/data.csv",blackhole);
}
```

Edit: updated code for bytes.
Final results are

```
Benchmark                      Mode  Cnt  Score   Error  Units
FileReader.compress            avgt   20  0.160 ± 0.005   s/op
FileReader.normal              avgt   20  1.818 ± 0.235   s/op
FileReader.normalCompressSize  avgt   20  0.150 ± 0.001   s/op
```

Comment: are you measuring CPU cycles, wall clock time, ... or what?

Comment: I am using JMH with these annotations 
  @Benchmark
  @BenchmarkMode(Mode.AverageTime)
  @OutputTimeUnit(TimeUnit.SECONDS)

Comment: Reading a gzipped file with a reader doesn't make much sense. A gzip file doesn't contain characters.

Comment: It contains bytes which can be casted to char. Also I understand it will be gibberish for code without proper inflator. Orignally I started with GzipInputStream but time diff was huge so I started narrowing down this is part which puzzles me.

Comment: A reader doesn't just cast bytes to chars. It uses a character encoding (a Charset) to decode byte sequences into characters. This can be very simple for some encodings, and more complex for others. UTF8 for example has characters encoded in 1, 2 or more bytes, and some byte sequences are invalid.

Comment: Inside the concrete Reader classes are CharsetDecoders that converts bytes to characters of the underlying character set. When you feed it random binary bytes that don't correspond to valid characters you will force the decoder into the more expensive error processing paths.

Comment: You are measuring time to convert compressed binary data into 16-bit Unicode characters even though it isn't an encoding of characters in the first place. You're not doing anything valid,so the time it takes is of no interest.

Comment: Thanks for input, let me check

Comment: Now I can actually work on actual problem, I didnt realized Decoder would be messing with result.